# How do I add lodash debounce to my project using Laravel Mix

Tags: javascript, lodash, yarnpkg, laravel-mix

I am new to using laravel mix and Yarn (coming from Codekit), so please bear with me! I have my `webpack.mix.js` file in my project which looks like this:

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');
const tailwindcss = require('tailwindcss');
const purgeCss = require('laravel-mix-purgecss');

mix.postCss('./source/styles/styles.css', './public/assets/css/', [
  tailwindcss('./tailwind.js'),
]);

mix.scripts([
    './source/scripts/app.js',
], './public/assets/js/app.js');

mix.copyDirectory('./source/fonts', './public/assets/fonts');

mix.copy('./source/images/', './public/assets/img/');

mix.copy('./source/root_files/', './public/');

mix.purgeCss({
  enabled: true,
  globs: [
    path.join(__dirname, './public/*.html'),
    path.join(__dirname, './public/assets/*.js'),
  ],
  extensions: ['html', 'js', 'php'],
});

mix.browserSync({
  proxy: 'something.loc',
  files: [ './public/*.html', './public/assets/**/*.*' ]
});
```

This is currently working fine and doing everything I want.

Now I want to add `lodash.debounce` and `lodash.throttle` so I can use those functions in my `app.js` file. I have added them both to my project using `yarn add`, and they are there in my `node_modules` folder.

My question is what do I do next? I have tried adding the `index.js` file from the `node_modules` folder like so:

```
mix.scripts([
    './node_modules/lodash.debounce/index.js',
    './source/scripts/app.js',
], './public/assets/js/app.js');
```

This builds using `yarn dev`, but then I get a console error on my page: `ReferenceError: module is not defined`

I am new to this way of working so it is probably something obvious, thanks for any help!

**UPDATE**

I have now tried using the following in my `webpack.mix.js` file:

```
mix.js('./source/scripts/app.js', './public/assets/js/app.js');
```

And added this to my `/source/scripts/app.js` file:

```
const debounce = require('lodash.debounce');
const throttle = require('lodash.throttle');

window.onresize = _.debounce(() => {
  console.log('resized!')
}, 100)
```

When I build and open the console I get this error:

```
ReferenceError: _ is not defined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using `require` inside your `source/scripts/app.js` file. This is normally what you should do for any JavaScript modules added via Yarn.

```
// source/scripts/app.js
const debounce = require('lodash.debounce');
const throttle = require('lodash.throttle');
```

What you've got is telling `laravel-mix` that your application has two entry points. When it tries to turn those files into a single bundle, its doesn't know what to do with the module.exports statement inside the lodash dependancy so it just leaves it there, hence the browser console error.

Comment: Hi Benjamin, thanks for the answer. Please see my edit above with what I have tried based on your reply - it's still not working as I would hope

Comment: Change your debounce call to:

`
window.onresize = debounce(() => {
  console.log('resized!')
}, 100)
`

As that is what you've imported it as